# Adding list to dictionary while updating occurrences of a string with a counter

Tags: python

I am having troubles updating my dictionary and matching the key value pairs.
My program should split a string into a list of words. Then it should update a dictionary that keeps track of each unique word in the list along with its count.
For example, the output should resemble something like this:

```
string = "asdf asdf asdf hello hello hello world"
```

then my program would print

```
{'asdf': 3, 'hello': 3, 'world': 1}
```

my code looks like this:

```
    dicto = {}
    user = input("enter some text: ")
    listo = []
    listo = user.split()
    for i in range (len(listo)):
        count = 1
        dicto = {listo[i]: count}
        if listo[i] in dicto:
            count = count + 1
    print dicto
```

and the output for my string example is:

```
    {'world': 1}
```

Comment: You overwrite `dicto` in every iteration

Comment: Yeah, use dictio[i] = count.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a tool that does exactly that:

```
from collections import Counter

string = "asdf asdf asdf hello hello hello world"
c = Counter(string.split())
print(c)
```

This yields:

> Counter({'asdf': 3, 'hello': 3, 'world': 1})

Counter has many useful functions, for example getting the least common word.

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 0):

```
somestr = "asdf asdf asdf hello hello hello world"

words = somestr.split(" ")
unique_words = set(words)

words_counts = {}

for word in unique_words:
    words_counts[word] = somestr.count(word)

print(words_counts)
```